# A single command with multi cores

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, opensuse

I would like to use a virtual screening program with parallel processing. Program is the [LIGSIFT](http://cssb.biology.gatech.edu/LIGSIFT). Is there any way to use this program with multi cores?

My command is

```
LIGSIFT -ql ligand.mol2 -db database.mol2 -o result.txt
```

My database file is very bulky with 14 million lines.

I am using openSUSE Leap 42.1 (x86_64) with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I have no clue about ligsift, but can you split your db or your db-request into chunks? If yes you can start ligsift several times and your os (no matter which one) will take care of a proper parallel execution. Best regards, Georg